# phpCHART with apache virtual port does not work

Tags: php, graph, charts

I am trying to setup phpCHART with apache virtual port.
I have followed these instructions: https://phpchart.com/examples/
I do notice in below mentioned error message that there are some extra [/] but removing the [/] from defined path in conf.php does not help.

**Question:**

Assuming to have followed instructions, is there something obviously wrong with my setup?.

---

Some checks:

- The phpChartLite is extracted and moved to [/var/www/phpChart_Lite].
- I have checked permissions on [/var/www/phpChart_Lite].
- I can access [localhost:1000] and see the file structure from [/var/www/phpChart_Lite].
- Secured that the index.php does include the content from
  conf.php.

---

**The conf.php in [/var/www/phpChart_Lite].**

```
define('SCRIPTPATH', '/phpChart_Lite/');
define('DEBUG', true);
require_once('phpChart.php');
```

**Location of index file:**

```
[/var/www/phpChart_Lite/test/index.php]
```

**Content of index file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    require_once('../conf.php');

    $pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array(11, 9, 5, 12, 14)), 'basic_chart');
    $pc->draw();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Configuration of apacahe virtual port.**

(/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:1000>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/phpChart_Lite
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 1000
```

The error message:

```
Warning: require_once(/var/www/phpChart_Lite//phpChart//conf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/phpChart_Lite/server/cls_conf.php(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/phpChart_Lite//phpChart//conf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/phpChart_Lite/server/cls_conf.php(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 5
```

Comment: Shouldn't SCRIPTPATH be empty since your doc root is set to be inside the folder? (Just going by the docs, never used this and probably never will).

Comment: @Jonnix Makes sence since when I remove the [/] from the SCRIPTPATH I get the [phpChart_Lite] twice.

Comment: @Jonnix Your suggestion solved the question as such. All examples in the folder structure now works. Have still some issues with that graph is not fully rendered but that is not part of this question. Please move your comment to an answer and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example page there's a comment against the `SCRIPTPATH` definition (in an unhelpful colour scheme) that states:

`// /phpChart/ is the absolute path to the phpChart files assuming phpChart folder is a folder in the web root.`

Since the DocumentRoot is set to inside the phpChart folder (or phpChart_Lite in this case), SCRIPTPATH should probably be set to either `/` or empty to fix paths.